# How do I get this dynamics to follow this trajectory?

Tags: control-theory

Given this dynamics:

$$x_{k+1} = x_k + a\cos(u_k)$$
$$y_{k+1} = y_k + a\sin(u_k)/\cos(x_k) $$

I want the input that would make this system ($x$ and $y$ states) follow this trajectory (lemniscate):

$$x^* = x_c + r\cos(t)/(1+\sin^2(t))$$
$$y^* = y_c + r\cos(t)\sin(t)/(1+\sin^2(t))$$

The problem is that if I compute from this the input that matches this dynamics it is:

$$\cos(u_k) = (x_{k+1}-x_k)/a$$
$$\sin(u_k) = (y_k+1-y_k)\cos(x_k)/a $$

And therefore:

$$\tan(u_k) = \frac{(y_{k+1}-y_k)\cos(x_k)}{(x_{k+1}-x_k)}$$

I compute this and apply it to the linearized system (with a controller) and it does not follow the given trajectory. However, if I go from a sinusoidal input and tune some parameters, I am completely able to follow a trajectory that is close to the lemniscate. I don't know why I cannot do this going the other way around.

Thanks!

Comment: From $\left(x_k,y_k\right)$ to $\left(x_{k+1},y_{k+1}\right)$ is $\Delta t$ a constant?

Comment: EDIT. Sorry, I didn't get the question. Yes, the sampling time is a constant.

Comment: And $x_k$ is both a coordinate of a moving object and an angle?

Comment: Yes, $x_k$ and $y_k$ are angular coordinates of an object.

Comment: When you say linearized dynamics, what exactly do you mean (can you write it out please)? In general, the linearized dynamics are only accurate near the fixed-point you linearized around, and not on arbitrary trajectories.

Comment: When I say linearized dynamics, I mean that I convert the non-linear system into a linear time varying system, as follows:$$\Delta z_{k+1} = A_k \Delta z_k + B_k \Delta u_k $$ where$$A_k = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}, B_k = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$$ with the partial derivatives evaluated at the equilibrium point $(x^*,y^*)$. Also, $$z_k = (x_k,y_k)^T$$ and $$z_{k+1} = f(z_k,u_k)$$ are the non-linear dynamics.